# how to find seconds left in a day,in sql?

Tags: sql

how to find seconds left in a day,in sql ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Try to explain what you are trying and what result you are expecting.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. When it comes to date/time many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS SQL this might be one of the ways

```
select 86400 - (DATEPART(second, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 60 * DATEPART(minute, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 3600 * DATEPART(hour, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, substituting getdate() for your date field:

```
DATEDIFF(SS, getdate(),convert(date,dateadd(day,1,getdate())))
```